# c# VirtualQueryEx непрвильно работает?

Tags: c#, .net

Пытаюсь сделать инъекция байтов в процесс 64х битной игры, так как байтов много приходиться искать кейв адрес в процессе игры но, VirtualQueryEx как то не правильно работает, сравнил с программой VMMap
[image: C#]

[image: VMMap]

C# вообще не находит свободные адреса. Как заставить находит эти свободные места в пространстве игры.

```
IntPtr handle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, proc.Id); 

            SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo = new SYSTEM_INFO();
            GetSystemInfo(ref sysinfo);

            long MaxAddress = (Int64)sysinfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;
            long address = 0;
            do
            {
                MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION m;
                UIntPtr result = VirtualQueryEx(handle, (IntPtr)address, out m, (int)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)));

                ListViewItem l = new ListViewItem(m.BaseAddress.ToString("X8"));
                l.SubItems.Add(m.AllocationBase.ToString("X8"));
                l.SubItems.Add(m.RegionSize.ToString());
                l.SubItems.Add(m.State.ToString());
                l.SubItems.Add(m.AllocationProtect.ToString());
                l.SubItems.Add(m.Protect.ToString("X3"));
                l.SubItems.Add(m.Type.ToString());
                l.SubItems.Add(m.__alignment1.ToString("X8"));
                l.SubItems.Add(m.__alignment2.ToString("X8"));

                address = (long)m.BaseAddress + (long)m.RegionSize;
            } while (address <= MaxAddress);
```

довольно распространенный код.

Comment: Из двух вариантов: неправильно работает библиотечная функция и неправильно написан код, который её использует — как вы думаете, какой чаще встречается?

Comment: Я искал другие коды, когда не нашел, пытался понят как вообще работает этот АПИ но не понял. Может вы тоже пытались это сделать, поделитесь кодом.